# Remove shortjournal field if it matches journal (BibLaTeX and biber)

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm using `biber` and `BibLaTeX` on a `.bib` file exported from Bookends. This mostly works really well. I have a few journal articles though that end up, for various reasons, with the `journal` and `shortjournal` fields identical. I want to do a map which checks to see if `journal` and `shortjournal` are identical and omits the `shortjournal` field if so.

Here is an example entry:

```
@Article{Larsen1977,
author = {Larsen, Mogens Trolle}, 
title = {Partnerships in the Old Assyrian Trade}, 
journal = {Iraq}, 
shortjournal = {Iraq}, 
volume = {39}, 
number = {1}, 
pages = {119--145}, 
year = {1977}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally this should be fixed on the `.bib` export side. Depending on your actual use case for `shortjournal` it may not be necessary to get rid of these cases at all.

Here is a sourcemap that should do it, though,

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journal, fieldtarget=journaltitle]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=journaltitle, match=\regexp{\A(.*)\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldsource=shortjournal, match=\regexp{\A$1\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=shortjournal, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Larsen1977,
  author       = {Larsen, Mogens Trolle}, 
  title        = {Partnerships in the Old Assyrian Trade}, 
  journal      = {Iraq}, 
  shortjournal = {Iraq}, 
  volume       = {39}, 
  number       = {1}, 
  pages        = {119--145}, 
  year         = {1977},
}
@article{test2,
  author       = {John Tumble},
  title        = {A Tremendously Interesting Idea},
  journal      = {Journal of Tremendously Interesting Ideas},
  shortjournal = {JTII},
  volume       = {1},
  number       = {1},
  year         = {1946},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,Larsen1977,test2}

\printbiblist{shortjournal}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```